# Disable scrolling if the cursor is over element

Tags: wpf, scroll

I wanted to disable the scrolling when the cursor is over an element in WPF.
[image]

If the mouse is over the red rectangle, the scroll should be disabled.
The red rectangle is on a scrollviewer.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converter:MouseOverToScrollBarVisibility x:Key="scrollVisibility" />
</Window.Resources>
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding IsMouseOver,
                ElementName=rec,
                Converter={StaticResource scrollVisibility}}">
    <Rectangle Height="50" Width="50" Fill="Red" x:Name="rec"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Then just define this converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(ScrollBarVisibility))]
sealed class MouseOverToScrollBarVisibility : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((bool)value) ? ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden : ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. And I would like to keep the scrollbars visibles. Is it possible ?

Comment: @Ben, just return `ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled` instead of `ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden` in converter.

Comment: Why is there no difference between "disabled" and "hidden" ?